# Deserialise JSON with unnecessary array as first item

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

```
[{
        "$type": "foo",
        "key" : "value"
}]
```

I don't serialise this message, its done as part of a framework.
The array is unnecessary, I'm just interested in first type and values etc, this is invariable.

I **CAN** do it using the following code, but it just feels a bit nasty! I know I am being particularly stupid, I started going down the road of creating a SerializationBinder but then thought I would like to get on with my life.  It can't be that hard!

```
                var json = reader.ReadToEnd().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']');
                var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json , new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                });
```

Comment: The JSon string is an array of foo. Why not deserialize into an array and take the first element. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo[]>(json)[0]`

Comment: Also, I went down the JsonReader route too, with this approach an additional call to Read gets you past the first token, but then TypeNameHandling is knobbled.

Comment: @Nico - Ha ha. Thanks. It is 2.30am in the UK :)  (Edit**)And I am stupid, like I said.

Comment: i have added an answer to ensure others with the same issue can resolve this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As based on the comments the `JSON` string in the example is a valid JSON Array. Therefore the best solution would be to parse the JSON as an Array and then capture the first element. A basic example would be.

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo[]>(json)[0]
```

For a safer way to handle this would be to first get the array and then check if the result is valid such as.

```
Foo foo = fooArray.Length > 0 ? fooArray[0] : null;
```

And for a more generic solution can be done as a generic method.

```
static T DeserializeObjectFromArray<T>(string json)
    where T: class
{
    var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(json);
    return arr != null && arr.Length > 0 ? arr[0] : null;
}
```

Where in this method you can simply call

```
Foo foo = DeserializeObjectFromArray<Foo>(json);
```

This does the same as the second solution but can be reused for generic classes.

Cheers.

Comment: I deleted this comment but I thought it worth saying that $type is not honored unless specifying JsonSerializationSettings with TypeNameHandling set appropriately.  I had funnies where a Bar was desrialising into a Foo as they share alot of properties. Would be nice if this was default behaviour given you pass in a type to Dserialize....

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize this to a list of dictionary like below

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(a);
```

Comment: Wont that return a list of dictionaries? That isnt even close to his real Json.. Not to mention the type is supplied.

Comment: Yes this return  list of dictionaries. he want the first item.

Comment: actually returns 2 values, `$type, foo` becomes the first element of the array. So you could say take the second value. However what if the type isnt included in the json string? Not to mention now he has a list and a dictionary which makes it a bigger headache. Best to just parse as a typed array.